# Tomcat starting failure due to timeout in Spring source

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

The issue is : i'm getting timeout errors when starting tomcat inside eclipse and it doesn't start at all in debug  mode.

debug mode error :

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741]
```

normal mode error : `Server Tomcat v7.0 at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time...`

Please not that i'm starting tomcat without any application deployed.

I've checked ports and they are not used for sure.

Any idea please?

Comment: Add more time than 45 seconds to start your Tomcat on Eclipse/Server double click, Go to Timeouts section and increase the value in "Start (in seconds)".

Comment: @RicardoGonzales : I've increased the timeout but in vain.

Comment: Then check my answer. Hope it can helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add memory to tomcat launching (Xms and Xmx VM parameters) script and increase timeout time. This way, the process will never fire a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your JDWP is not loading. Here in [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/87270/Tomcat/ERROR-transport-error-connect-failed) article you can get an idea to resolve your problem. Check the answer from **Jaikiran Pai** in the post. He says that you must use the command line options to load your JDWP.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

Hope this can helps you.

Comment: when I add that i eclipse run command of tomcat, I have an error saying that start command already contains transport attribute...But when added outside eclipse it works. I want to start tomcat inside eclipse but not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `options:-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`